# How can i remove files from File Editor in a project that was upgraded from VS2008 to VS2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, setup-deployment

I'm used VS2008 to create a setup and deployment project that installed files to certain folders.

i recently started using VS2010 and pulled this project into VS2010 and tried to continue working on it. When i go into the Setup and Deployment File Editor no files are listed as being placed in any folders, but when i run the program there are.

how can i find and then remove these files from my VS2010 project?

Comment: Have you tried it with removing the bin & obj once after the conversion?

Comment: yes I have. I have also done a lot of clean builds and clean rebuilds. tried deleting the file editor folders (didn't work). MS says there is a bug and that there is a workaround but they dont attach the workaround.

Comment: Seems like a good question. +1 Btw, when you change your name people can address you in comments with @name

Comment: I even deleted the entire installation project itself and made a new one and it still installs the folders...

Comment: I have change product code of the installer. the Version and the upgrade code so far to no avail.

Comment: @Grant add such comments directly to the questions with a little edit mark, so that everyone see it if he reads your question. Don't expect a answer that fast... this may be a tricky question if it is as you described a sort of bug